# Count the number of cells containing a specific value ("N") in a specific row which contains a specific word("Hey")

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count the number of cells containing a specific value ("N") in a specific row which contains a specific word("Hey").

It counts fine for the first sheet but does not work for the next sheet.
Note: "Hey" is always in the second column however the position is not fixed

Here's what I have tried:

```
Private Sub macro1()
Dim SearchString As String
Dim far As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim c As Integer, count As Integer, i As Integer

c = 0
count = 0
SearchString = "Hey"
Application.FindFormat.Clear
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sh.Select
    Range("B1:B100").Select
    Set far = Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, _
        After:=sh.Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=True, _
        SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not far Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto far
        For i = 3 To 23
        c = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, i), "N")
        If c Then
        count = count + 1
        End If
        Next i
    End If
Next
MsgBox ("Count= " & count)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did work for me but I note that

- you are looking for an exact match of *Hey* using `xlWhole`. Use `xlPart` if you were looking to match "*A Hey is in this cell somewhere*"
- your code has un-necessary selects and the COUNTIF is being applied cell by cell rather than to a range

*updated code*

```
Private Sub macro1()
Dim SearchString As String
Dim far As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim c As Integer, count As Integer

SearchString = "Hey"

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Set far = sh.Range("B1:B100").Find(SearchString, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, True, False)
    If Not far Is Nothing Then
          c = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(far.Resize(1, 22), "N")
          count = count + c
    End If
Next
MsgBox ("Count= " & count)
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, Actually I have intentionally used xlWhole because I am looking for "Hey" alone and not as a part.

Comment: And I did not know about countif and thank you for removing the unnecessary selects.